# Creating MediaStream from series of images

Tags: html

Is it possible to create an HTML5 video element compatible MediaStream from a series of images (jpegs). Assume I have the jpeg urls, the FPS and frametime.

My use case is that I have some resources where 90% of them are encoded as mp4's (and thus I use HTML5 video player to play them). But 10% are legacy and very old, and are a series of jpegs that I blit to the canvas using request animation frame. If I could use the html5 video element, that would be ideal.